# How to use custom command when using SSH in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-server, openssh

I'd like to SSH a jumpserver in VSCode, and the SSH config is like this:

```
Host JumpServer
  HostName hostname
  User username
  Port 22
```

And when I connect to the jumpserver, VSCode outputs the following stuff

```
... ...
[22:06:06.401] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\ssh.exe ENOENT
[22:06:06.401] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe -V"
[22:06:06.403] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe ENOENT
[22:06:06.403] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe -V"
[22:06:06.404] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe ENOENT
[22:06:06.404] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -V"
[22:06:06.438] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2

[22:06:06.441] Running script with connection command: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -D 50434 "JumpServer" bash
[22:06:06.443] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
```

Where it automatically runs the following command in the terminal shell

```
"C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -D 50434 "JumpServer" bash
```

How can I use costum commands when I connect the JumpServer? For example, I'd like to run

```
"C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -D 50434 "JumpServer"
```

without `-T` and `bash`, so what should I do?

I tried to modify the config files, but I cannot solve it.

Answer (score 0):

They way to do this is documented: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_remember-hosts-and-advanced-settings. When adding a new SSH host, in the input that says "Enter SSH Connection Command", you can either enter a host name, or an SSH command to use to make the connection. Enter an SSH command to use.

Comment: Hi, I tried to type this `ssh username@jumperserver` in the command line, but it still runs `Running script with connection command: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -D 50892 "JumpServer" bash`, where it automatically add `-T` `-D 50892` and `bash`.
It seems `-T` and `bash` does not work when I'm connecting to the jumpserver.